# How to get time in AM and PM from a DateTime String in Android from a .vcs file

Tags: utc, datetime-format, android-calendar, vcalendar

I am parsing a .vcs file and it just has the date-time in the below format. For example-The start date-time of the event is in the below format:

DTSTART:20000803T103000Z

Since I have this string I can easily find out the values of hour, mins, day, month , year etc. and display it easily in readable format.
But I want to show AM and PM also with time. How can I do this?
Which Android function can I use to get AM and PM from this string. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                     hour = StartDate.substring(9,11);
             minutes= StartDate.substring(11,13);
             hoursofday = Integer.parseInt(hour);
             minutesofday = Integer.parseInt(minutes);      



if(hourOfDay>12)
    {

        datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay-12)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
    }
    if(hourOfDay==12)
    {
        datehid.setText("12"+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
    }
    if(hourOfDay<12)
    {
        datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"am"));
    }
```

Comment: After a lot of struggle, finally I found this code which would resolve my issue.